# Retrieving Sheets/Worksheets objects without making the function volatile

Tags: vba, excel, volatile

I'm trying to make a non volatile function that accepts an index and two ranges and makes certain operation on the sheet's ranges.

Unfortunately the `Sheets` or `Worksheets` functions make the function volatile thus each time I edit the worksheet the function starts recalculation.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
Function FooFunc(sheetIndex As Integer, xRange As Variant, yRange As Variant) As Variant    

   Dim operatingSheet As Variant

   'This makes the function volatile
   Set operatingSheet = Sheets("Bar " & sheetIndex)

   [...]

End Function
```

Apparently declaring `Application.Volatile (False)` doesn't seem to change anything.

As per title: is there a way to retrieve Sheets/Worksheets object without making the function volatile?

Comment: Since you are not returning a value from the function, use a sub instead.  You can call it on demand.

Comment: Why would Excel be considering this volatile function? Are you using it in a formula? Or calling it from a Worksheet event?

Comment: For UDF's, Excel only looks at the parameters to decide whether, when they should be recalculated.  Your parameters do not tell Excel exactly where the inputs are, so it will not auto-recalculate when the "real" inputs change.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's "volatile" though - it should not be unless you flag it as such.  I think we need a bit more information here.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Sorry, I was trying to focus on the Sheets function and I left out the return part.

Comment: @dbmitch I'm calling the function from a cell (using `=FooFunc(1,A1:A10,B1:B10)`). If I omit the `Sheets` call in code, Excel doesn't consider it volatile anymore.

Comment: Not really. You can either globally disable automatic calculation with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, or you can employ some global switch within the func like `If boolCalcDisabled Then Return` with which Excel will still call the function quite often but with a reduced load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your observation that accessing a worksheet from a VBA UDF causes that UDF to be volatile (Excel 2013).

Simple UDF:

```
Function Tester(num, rng As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rv

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(num)

    rv = num & ":" & rng.Value & ":" & ws.Name
    Debug.Print rv

    Tester = rv

End Function
```

[image]

I only see debug output from this UDF when editing the input ranges A2 and A3: other edits or calculations on the same sheet do not trigger output.

The only way i can see what you describe it to add `Application.Volatile` to the UDF.